# How to go about changing an angularjs angular-material internal SASS !default variable?

Tags: css, angularjs, sass, angular-material

I'm using angularjs along with the angular-material framework. I started writing my project based on the [angular-seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) project.

In my project I have a form that contains `<md-select>` elements. My problem is that the selection view is always only as big as 5 select options. I want to see more options when scrolling.

I looked around the angular-material source code and found [this !default SASS variable](https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/src/components/select/select.scss#L9) which controls how many options are displayed. I want to make it bigger.

The way I understand it, !default means SASS will ignore the value of that variable if it's already defined elsewhere.

But I also understand that the SASS preprocessor takes a single SASS file as input and outputs a single CSS file - which means I can't override a SASS variable in one file from another file.

I'm also quite confused on which component is responsible for compiling the .scss files found in the angular-material framework and at what stage are they compiled. Are they compiled when installed by Bower? Are they compiled when I call `npm start`?

I'm new to all these technologies so even though those stuff might seem trivial, I don't really know what to search for to find answers to these questions, I tried and found nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I just looked around and realized that the angular-material Bower package comes with css files that have already been pre-processed from scss files. There's nothing I can do to affect that variable.

To show more options in the md-select component I just resorted to the ugly solution of adding these hard-coded pre-calculated attributes to my stylesheets:

```css
md-select-menu {
    max-height: 784px !important; }

    md-select-menu md-content {
    max-height: 784px !important; }
```

EDIT:
Actually I found this solution even nicer:

```css
md-select-menu {
    max-height: 100vh !important; }

    md-select-menu md-content {
    max-height: 100vh !important; }
```

It fills as much of the view as possible with options